# Multiple comparison problems for Unit Root testing

Tags: time-series, forecasting, multiple-comparisons, unit-root

Lets say I have a multivariate time series and I will run unit root tests for each variable to figure out if the variable is stationary and how many differencing are necessary to make it stationary.

If I am only doing forecasting, which is a prediction task, do I need to worry about the multiple comparisons problem in these unit root tests?
What about if I am doing some sort of time series inference?